# CGAffineTransformScale a UIButton

Tags: iphone, xcode, animation, uiview, uibutton

i am trying to scale in and out a UIButton in the main view, when i press a action button at first, the button zooms in and when i press it again it zooms out but when i press it again to zoom in.. nothing happens.. here is my code:

THE METHODS TO ZOOM IN AND ZOOM OUT ARE IN A OBJECTIVE-C CATEGORY ON UIVIEW

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
[super viewDidLoad];

//this button is being added in the storyboard
[self.viewToZoom removeFromSuperview];

}

- (IBAction)zoomButton:(id)sender {

if (isShown) {
    [self.view removeSubviewWithZoomOutAnimation:self.viewToZoom duration:1.0 option:0];
    isShown = NO;
} else {
    [self.view addSubviewWithZoomInAnimation:self.viewToZoom duration:1.0 option:0];
    isShown = YES;
}

}

UIView+Animation.m


- (void) addSubviewWithZoomInAnimation:(UIView*)view duration:(float)secs option:(UIViewAnimationOptions)option {

CGAffineTransform trans = CGAffineTransformScale(view.transform, 0.01, 0.01);

view.transform = trans; // do it instantly, no animation
[self addSubview:view];
// now return the view to normal dimension, animating this tranformation
[UIView animateWithDuration:secs delay:0.0 options:option
                 animations:^{
                     view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(view.transform, 100.0, 100.0);
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     NSLog(@"done");
                 } ];   
}


- (void) removeSubviewWithZoomOutAnimation:(UIView*)view duration:(float)secs option:(UIViewAnimationOptions)option {

// now return the view to normal dimension, animating this tranformation
[UIView animateWithDuration:secs delay:0.0 options:option
                 animations:^{
                     view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(view.transform, 0.01, 0.01);

                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     [view removeFromSuperview];
                 }];    
}
```

Thanks,
Newton

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Newton, when `removeSubviewWithZoomOutAnimation` ends the `view.transform` is an affine transform that scaled the view's original size down to 0.01. The problem is that when you call `addSubviewWithZoomInAnimation` the second time you're again scaling down by 0.01, but now the `view.transform` will be scaled down to 0.0001, which is not what you're looking for.

Simply add `view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;` at the beginning of both animations like this:

```
- (void) addSubviewWithZoomInAnimation:(UIView*)view duration:(float)secs option:(UIViewAnimationOptions)option {
    view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity; 
    CGAffineTransform trans = CGAffineTransformScale(view.transform, 0.01, 0.01);

    view.transform = trans; // do it instantly, no animation
    [self addSubview:view];
    // now return the view to normal dimension, animating this tranformation
    [UIView animateWithDuration:secs delay:0.0 options:option
                     animations:^{
                         view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(view.transform, 100.0, 100.0);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         NSLog(@"done");
                     } ];   
}


- (void) removeSubviewWithZoomOutAnimation:(UIView*)view duration:(float)secs option:(UIViewAnimationOptions)option {
    view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    // now return the view to normal dimension, animating this tranformation
    [UIView animateWithDuration:secs delay:0.0 options:option
                     animations:^{

                         view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(view.transform, 0.01, 0.01);

                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                         [view removeFromSuperview];
                     }];    
}
```

I also suggest you to pass the `UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState` UIViewAnimationOptions which improves the animation result when quickly zooming in and out.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Dude, awesome.. i didnt see that..!! i will test it at home and give u your thumbs up.. ;) Thanks.